# Authenticate AWS API gateway with AWS_IAM and API key from REST client Postman

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, postman, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to access authenticated POST API gateway with postman rest client, but I am getting status 403 with forbidden message.

{
  "message": "Forbidden"
}

I am using AWS Signature Authentication with AccessKey, SecretKey, AWS Region and Service Name. I don't understand why its not allowing my rest call, is it something to do with my AccessKey and SecretKey pair lacking authorisation?? (My user is Admin thought)

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/score",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "input1=1&input2=2",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: AAAA-AAAA-XXX123 Credential=XXXXXXXXXX/20160414/us-west-2/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=sdddddssdddddddddddddddddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsd",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/javascript",
    "host: xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
    "postman-token: abf462fe-24ae-244d-ba8d-d3e953f0e712",
    "x-amz-date: 20160414T084331Z"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an API Key, make sure you set the "x-api-key" header.

I also had the same problem until I created a Usage Plan and linked the plan to the API stage and the API key.

Answer (score 3):

If you set 'API Key Required' option to true, please check below.

1. Deploy your API to update changes.
2. you have to pass 'x-api-key' HTTP Header Parameter to API Gateway.
3. The API Key had to be created.
4. In addition, you need to check a Usage Plan for the API Key on API Gateway Console.

Answer (score 1):

This can have multiple reasons, would you mind sharing a sample setup where it fails?

Please check the following:

1. Did you deploy your API?
2. Does the user have the proper permissions? You can use the managed IAM policy "AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess" or create your own. Please refer to our [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html) for more details.

Best,

Jurgen, API Gateway

Comment: I have checked permission with simulator and indeed user have authority to invoke api and I have deploy API as well.
API works fine without authentication but when I add authentication with IAM and API Key I am not able to access. I am sure its something with auth but I am not able identify it.

PS: I have added Code in question.

Comment: There seemed to be some issues with postman and AWS authorization recently (see https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/360). This was a PATCH operation though, not sure if it was the same issue with POST. Could you try to update your postman client?

Comment: I am using POST method not a PATCH method as mention in issue and I am with latest version of postman which is v 4.1.3

Answer (score 0):

It often happens when API is not deployed to API Gateway or you are accessing the wrong path /your-rout instead of /api-name/your-route.